# HOWTO: Paint a dotted line in .NET (WinForms)

Tags: winforms

How can i draw a dotted line in .NET/WinForms/GDI+?

```
Pen p = new Pen (Color.Black)
```

gives me only solid line pen.

I am trying to have a dotted (or dashed) lines; can't seem to be able to google it up successfully.

Will much appreciate any help on this one.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
p.DashStyle = DashStyle.Dash;
```

I believe.

Comment: for dotted line: `p.DashStyle = DashStyle.Dot;`

Answer (score 2):

Set the `DashStyle` property on your `Pen` object.